# How to store data in different array i c programming from a data file

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

Suppose I have the following two columns in a data file name data.txt

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

Now, I want to store the first column in one array and the second column in another array by using fscanf. Can someone tell me how to do it?

```
void main()
{


float a[20] b[20];
int i;


FILE* read = fopen("data.txt","r");

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fscanf(read, "%f", &a[i]);
        
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

The above code does not do the job. Is there any way to do it? I want to store first column in a[] and second in b[].

Comment: So explain to us why there are no lines where something is stored in `b`. You say you want to, but you don't.

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile...

Comment: Perhaps `int elems = 0; while(elems < 20 && fscanf(read, "%f%f", &a[elems], &b[elems]) == 2) { elems++; }`

Comment: @Cheatah it is just a sample by which I am telling, I do not know how to do it. It should be something like this but do not know exactly. If you run this code, it will store everything in a[].

Comment: and use `elems` for the output loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should scan first element to a[], then second element to b[]. And so on.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fscanf(read, "%f", &a[i]);
        fscanf(read, "%f", &b[i]);
}
```